# Is there a method to read pdf or doc document in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, xpdf

I want to read pdf or doc document's text content in wordpress plugin. I downloaded xpdf and I used it to get content. But in wordpress plugin or theme I can't get the content.

```
$filename = "try.pdf";
echo $filename;
$content = shell_exec('xpdf\pdftotext ' . $filename . ' -');
echo $content;
```

I used this code in plugin, but $content variable is null. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Guessing in the dark but I believe the path to the file is different resulting in the null content.

Comment: Does this help? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pdf-and-ppt-viewer/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string via `shell_exec` function, but this function is disabled when PHP is running in `safe mode`.
If you do not get the output from the executed command, then `NULL` is returned if an error occurred. Most probably you have also (if you are running PHP is safe mode) a permissions problem on your hosting server.
Try to get the file contents by avoiding `shell_exec` function and using regular file manipulation functions like `fopen`, `fread`, `file_get_contents`.